# Error 3004: No mapping specified for properties Invoice.IdEx in Set

Tags: c#, entity-framework, edmx, edmx-designer

I get this compilation error :

> Error 3004: Problem in mapping fragments :No mapping specified for properties Invoice.IdEx in Set Invoices.IdEx An Entity with Key (PK) will not round-trip when:   Entity is type [Models.Invoice]   C:\Workspace\PrDomainModel\EntityFramework\Model.edmx DomainModel

I try to delete `Invoice.IdEx` in my edmx (this field is no longer present in my DB). But after that my `ModelGenerator` is empty even if I run custom tool.

IdEx is a FK but there is no link anymore.

Comment: You may have table imported to model contains non-mapped additional column `Invd`. Also you may need to remove other table with FK field linked on `IdEx` together, then re-generate model from database.

Comment: Thanks Tetsuya it works for now !